# How can I make my circle responsive only with CSS?

Tags: css, responsive

I have a rectangular `div` that contains a circle with an image in it. My design is responsive, and I can't figure out how to make my circle responsive.  I've read other posts mentioning the same `vw` and `vh` but that won't work for me. Neither having the same `width` and `padding-top` .

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/xxVwboV?editors=1100)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "make circle responsive"?

Comment: Good point, i made a guess :D

Comment: What I mean by "make circle responsive" is that I need the circle to remain a circle always. In my actual code, it goes from a circle to an oval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

`<div class="card-premium-category col">`

instead of

`<div class="card-premium-category col-3">`.

[Fiddle](https://codepen.io/sirpilan/pen/VwavLLz).

Comment: could you explain what different `col` does than `col-3`?

Comment: Sure i could, or you just read the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), you might learn a thing there :)